# Did the writers know Odo’s heritage and the details of changing society from the start?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

During the DS9 series the Changling/Dominion society becomes a key part of the narrative. I have been trying to look online and while I can see quotes about how Odo was written to take on the role of Data and Spock, a non human looking in on human society. I can’t find anything that explains when the writers fleshed out his backstory and came up with the idea of changlings being the society they became in the series?

Was it always intended that Odo would find his fellow changlings and they would then be the main antagonist or is this something that developed over time?

Comment: Nope. Total ass-pull when they run out of ideas

Comment: I had a feeling that may be the case but any details about this anywhere, would be interested when, why and how they went in that direction

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Founder#Conceptual_origins - I can't be fussed to run down the quotes and check they're accurate, but I've got no reason to doubt that they are

Comment: Reading that happy for you to compose an answer including that link and I will accept it :)